# I want to wait until the Shadow DOM elements are loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I am developing a Chrome extension.

I would like to develop a feature that when you Hover an element on the page, a frame appears around the element, but it doesn't work with the Shadow DOM element.

I believe this is due to the fact that the shadow dom element is not loaded on the page at the time the load event fires.

This is especially true for pages with nested shadow doms.
ex.) https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do

However, I do not know how to detect that the entire page, including the shadow dom, has finished loading.

Please let me know if you know of a solution.

```js
function addAttribute(e) {
  const el = e.path || (e.composedPath && e.composedPath());
  el.setAttribute('style', "outline: solid 4px !important");
}

function removeAttribute(e) {
  const el = e.path || (e.composedPath && e.composedPath());
  el.removeAttribute('style', "outline: solid 4px !important");
}

function addEventListenerToShadow(root) {
  const tw = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
  
  do {
    const currentNode = tw.currentNode;
    if (currentNode instanceof ShadowRoot) continue;
    if (currentNode.shadowRoot) {
      currentNode.shadowRoot.addEventListener('mouseover', addAttribute)
      currentNode.shadowRoot.addEventListener('mouseout', removeAttribute)
      addEventListenerToShadow(currentNode.shadowRoot);
    }
  } while (tw.nextNode());
}

window.onload = addEventListenerToShadow(document.body);
```

Comment: Use MutationObserver or setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(nested) shadowDOM are (DOM) children entering your class-room.

Only when you know how many there will come you know when the last one entered.

That means each (shadow) DOM/Element should notify it **will** come to the main application.

And the **application** then processes/counts down each "arrived" DOM Child/shadowDOM

The `connectedCallback` fires on the **opening** TAG of your Custom Element

So that is the appropriate time to send a `CustomEvent` **I_WILL_COME** to the application.

**BUT... in your use-case you do not have control over what components do.

So the only escape is just wait **N** seconds and consider your page loaded.**